# How to fill the browser window with a canvas element without creating scroll bars?

Tags: javascript, html, fullscreen

I have a problem to get my window size, I try this code:

**Javascript**

```
var game;
function game() {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    this.canvasWidth = window.innerWidth;
    this.canvasHeight = window.innerHeight;    
    this.initCanvas = function() {
        this.canvas.style.width = this.canvasWidth + "px";
        this.canvas.style.height = this.canvasHeight + "px";
    }
    this.run = function() {
        this.initCanvas();
    }
}
game = new game();
game.run();
```

I also have

**CSS**

```css
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I only have a canvas in my body.

Problem is, that  I have a vertical and horizontal scroll bar. This means the size of canvas is too large. How to make it of the window size without the scroll bars appearing?

Comment: What's the problem with your code though?

Comment: So what are you getting?

Comment: When you say window size, which window are you referring to? The browser window? The page dimensions?

Comment: sorry i forget my problem, I have a vertical and a horizontal scroll bar

Comment: Padding and margin should be `0px`, not 0, and semicolons aren't optional (except after the last property)

Comment: @TomSmilack You don't need "px", "em", etc on 0 propertys.

Comment: You're right, I was thinking of something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're just trying to make your canvas have a width and height of 100%. You can do this with just css:

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
canvas {
    background: #ffcccc;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
​
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RG6dn/)**

Or if you want to use your code but get rid of the scroll bars on the window, you need to specify `block` on the canvas tag.

**CSS**

```css
canvas {
    display: block;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RG6dn/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

When you use CSS to style your `<canvas>` element it will get scaled instead of sized.  Be sure to set the `.width` and `.height` properties on the `canvas` element instead (ie `canvas.width` not `canvas.style.width`).

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/RG6dn/2/)

In the example the first canvas element is scaled correctly, the second (using CSS) is not scaled properly.  This has to do with a default canvas element size (300x150) that CSS scales.

To prevent getting scrollbars when setting the `<canvas>` to the full window width/height set the `body` to `overflow:hidden;` as used in the jsfiddle above.